# GNU Grub Version 2.04 exists even after deleting all Ubuntu partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I had Windows 10, Ubuntu 18.04, and Ubuntu 20.04 on the same disk. Since I didn't need Ubuntu anymore, I decided to delete them. First deleted 20.04, but that wiped out the Grub bootloader. Somehow managed to boot into 18.04 and updated grub. But, the Grub CLI was still coming first. Since my Enter key doesn't work, it is a real pain. I finally decide to wipe out the 18.04 partitions as well but the CLI is still there. Currently I only have Windows partitions but the issue isn't resolved. What seems to be the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Prior to deleting an unwanted OS; you need to ensure it doesn't control the boot process (if machine has multiple OSes installed - only one can control boot). Each OS provides a command for this; `grub-install` is what Ubuntu OSes use; you need to boot whatever OS you're wanting to keep (sounds like windows 10) & use it's appropriate command for this function. This should be done before erasing the unwanted OS; otherwise windows 10 repair media provides a function for it; so use that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that grub still exist on your EFI partition. In order to delete it follow this guide:

On Windows you need to do the following in order to delete GRUB from the boot menu. Open a terminal as admin ( type `cmd` on the search menu ). Once on the terminal:

1. Type `bcdedit /enum firmware` and identify GRUB or Ubuntu from the output, copy the identifier which should be on curly braces.
2. Type `bcedit /delete "{identifier}" /f`
3. Type `diskpart`
4. Type `list vol` and identify the number of your EFI partition
5. Type `select vol number` where number is the number of your EFI partition
6. Type `assign letter=z:`
7. Type `exit`
8. Type `z:` and `cd EFI`, then `dir`
9. identify the GRUB or Ubuntu folder (it could be one of those 2 names) and do `rmdir /s ubuntu` or `rmdir /s grub` depending on the folder name.

Comment: 's answer is nice. I would also recommend doing it in command prompt. I was doing the `bcedit /delete "{identifier}"` step in powershell, and was facing some issue. Apart from that, I do know the use of `/f` in the bcdedit command. It worked without that.

Comment: In step 6, when I try to assign the drive letter, I receive a blocking error that says "Assigning or removing drive letters on the current boot or pagefile volume is not allowed." (Yes, I launched the CMD prompt as admin.) The volume I selected using diskpart is 0, which is listed as a 475 GB Windows boot partition (NTFS). (Volume 1 is a 260GB system partition and volume 2 is a 1 GB WinRE_DRV partition.) Any ideas what could be preventing me from setting a drive letter for the boot partition?